# Easiest way to convert wchar_t* to wstring*

Tags: c++, casting

I have a function `TransformString(wchar_t* inputString,...)` that modifies inputString, which somewhere along the way calls helper function `Help(wstring* string)`.

I would like to pass `wchar_t* inputString` to Helper function so that function can modify it. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: In general, you would create a `wstring` initialised with `inputString` and pass it to your helper function. However all this would do is modify your temporary `wstring` - to propagate the changes back to your original `inputString` depends on how that was created - you would need to check that it is large enough to contain the new string to avoid buffer overflows. You might want to consider refactoring `TransformString` to work on a `wstring` to begin with.

Comment: I was scared that was the only answer. Was hoping there is a pointer transformation I could do in order to avoid refactoring.

Comment: While at it, consider returning the string instead or at least using references.

Comment: Here is a very similar question, with stome relevant answers to you (instead of a helper function, it considers the case of a win api function):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715127/c-using-stdstring-stdwstring-as-a-buffer