# creating an initialization and deleting function for a c++ multi-dimensional pointer to class

Tags: c++, pointers

I created a class and using multi-dimensional pointer as follows:

```
variable **v_mod;
v_mod = new variable *[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    v_mod[i] = new variable [n];
}
```

and deleting pointer after using

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
{
    delete [] v_mod[i];
}
delete [] v_mod;
```

This is working perfectly fine but I am using many pointers. So can anyone help in writing a function in the class which helps in creating and deleting the pointers like

```
variable ** v_mod;
v_mod.create(3,n);

v_mod.delete();
```

and which works same way?

Comment: Why not use a vector of vectors?

Comment: @user2079303 [My thoughts exactly.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35630222/2642059)

Comment: Maybe he got a school assignment.

Comment: @HamzaAnis Sounds like a good C assignment. (Maybe that's too strong, I do expect C++ programmers to understand how dynamic memory works too.)

Comment: if done then `v_mod.create()`  should be `v_mod->create()`

Comment: hey @Jonathan, see if my answer meets the requirement. ;-)

Comment: @HamzaAnis Yikes please don't do this. This means that each *element* of your 2D-array will contain an uninitialized `variable**` and an uninitialized `int`. That's a memory waste of the number of elements (here 3 * 2 = 6) `* sizeof(variable**) * sizeof(int)`. `variable` is *not* a container, it's an element class, elements shouldn't have pointers to the whole container. If you want to try to reinvent an octagonal wheel you should at least make a separate class to contain the elements. For me, I'll take the standard implementation round wheel: `vector`.

Comment: Sure, using vectors is the best option. but just wondering how to do it without it.

Comment: @HamzaAnis I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35630222/2642059) with a couple of options that I don't think you should consider.

Comment: @HamzaAnis I've added [an example of how to work with these options](http://ideone.com/TD7Qcz) to [my answer]. The typing is a bit complex. I wanted to do it in a template, but I haven't been able to sort out just how to do that yet.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `new` use a [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
vector<vector<variable>> v_mod(3, vector<variable>(n));
```

This will require that your variable object has a generated or your own default constructor.

But other than that you can use the `vector` version of `v_mod` as you used the dynamically allocated array version, except that a `vector` cleans itself up when it goes out of scope. So no need to `delete`.

**EDIT:**

[@Hamza Anis has asked me how to do this without `vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629957/creating-an-initialization-and-deleting-function-for-a-c-multi-dimensional-poi/35630222#comment58946212_35629957), so I'm updating this answer to reflect a couple ways to do that. Let me preface this by saying, `vector` *is* the right way to do this, anything short of `vector` is simply making life harder on everyone who handles the code.

**Option 2 [`unique_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711846/2642059):**

```
unique_ptr<variable[]> v_mod[3];

for(auto& i : v_mod) {
    i = make_unique<variable[]>(n);
}
```

**Option 3 only do this if it's a homework assignment:**

```
variable* v_mod[3];

for(auto& i : v_mod) {
    i = new variable[n];
}

for(auto& i : v_mod) {
    delete[] i;
}
```

[[Complex Example using `int`s](http://ideone.com/TD7Qcz)]