# Work with unique_ptr<int[]>, vector<int>, and int[] in a Templatized Function

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, metaprogramming, c++17

Say that I have 3 variables:

```
vector<int> vec(3);
int stat[3];
auto dyn = make_unique<int[]>(3);
```

I can initialize any of these if I know the size is 3:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i) X[3] = i;
```

Where `X` is either, `vec`, `stat`, or `dyn`. But I'd like to be able to do this in a template just by passing in `X` again. What I'd need in order to do this is:

1. The contained type
2. The container size

Can I get that in a function like:

```
template <typename T>
void init(T& X);
```

Or am I unable to extract size information from the `unique_ptr`? Or type in a universal fashion? (I've marked this question C++17 in the hopes that [`size`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33442842/2642059) can be used.)

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)?

Comment: @ildjarn `iota` is great if you can use it. In my example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35630222/2642059 you'll see I do use `iota`. But how would I get iterators in the same way for all of these? I can't use `begin` or `end` on `dyn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to be able to get the size from the unique pointer.  When you use `auto dyn = make_unique<int[]>(3);` it gets translated to

```
make_unique<int[]>(new int[3]())
```

Which is a pointer and we lose the size information.  All the array overload does for unique pointer is change the `delete` call in the destruction to `delete[]`.  If you want to use an `unique_ptr` "array" then you wil need to pass the size.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this for `unique_ptr<T[]>` - that's still just a raw pointer that doesn't have any idea what its size is.

But any other container, you don't even need `size()`. Just C++11 suffices:

```
 template <class T>
 void init(T& container) {
     for (auto& elem : container) {
         elem = 3;
     }
 }
```

You can add SFINAE or a `static_assert` on top of that to ensure that the elements of `T` are actually assignable to `3`, but otherwise that suffices.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using a loop over the respective contents, then you actually don’t care for the actual containers or holders. This is a good time to be using a pair of iterators, an array view, or a range. E.g.:

```
template<typename It>
void init(It first, It last)
{
    // or use an algorithm, e.g. std::iota(first, last, 0)
    int i = 0;
    for(; first != last; ++last, ++i) *first = i;
}

// use as:
using std::begin;
using std::end;
init(begin(vec), end(vec));
init(begin(stat), end(stat));
init(dyn.get(), dyn.get() + 3);
```

Note that you either have to hardcode the size 3 in the `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` case, or keep track of it yourself somewhere in a variable. The size information is not available otherwise.