# Templatized Type Find for unique_ptr<int[]>, vector<int>, and int[]

Tags: c++, vector, types, containers, metaprogramming

Say that I have 3 variables:

```
vector<int> vec(3);
int stat[3];
auto dyn = make_unique<int[]>(3);
```

I want to make a templatized function that accepts all of these, and has a member variable of the contained type (in my examples that would be `int`). I have a templatized function like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& X) { vector<type> bar; }
```

I'm going to pass each container into this function. And I need a way to find this `type` which will work for each of them. I can obviously do this by specializing the templatized function, but I was hoping someone could provide me with a more eloquent solution.

Comment: How are you going to use this function? Will you fill the vector `bar` inside the function with the container passed as argument, and then do some processing on it? Why not create three specializations that populate the vector, and then call a another function which does all the actual work? Trying to cram all the different cases into a single function might seem like a good idea, but in reality it will most likely be just an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg To be honest this is purely academic. I asked a question about initializing these containers by passing them into a template here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35636160/2642059 The answers short circuited at the fact that I cannot find the size for `dyn` after construction, so I could not initialize them in a templatized function like that. But by that time I'd put some work into finding the type, but hadn't found anything that would work in all three cases, so I just wanted to see if there actually was a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `decltype`.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& x) {
    using type = std::decay_t<decltype(x[0])>;
    std::vector<type> bar;
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/056c76800b5dc923)

Comment: This is what I want, can you explain what's going on with `decay_t`? Cause I don't understand that.

Comment: `x[0]` would be of type `/*const*/ int&`. so you have to remove reference and cv qualifier. which is done with [decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay).

Comment: Wow, so I just tested it and we can do this even with empty vectors and dynamic arrays, so I'm not certain if I understand why you put the `[0]`. Don't we usually need `declval` to access functions?

Comment: `decltype` is compile time only. You just get the type (as `sizeof(x[0])` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`), no evaluation is done at runtime. You may indeed replace `x` by `std::declval<T&>()`, but it it just more verbose, and not clearer IMO. `std::declval` is needed in context where you don't have variable of the correct type, as for in template parameter, or for r-value reference.

Comment: Right, thanks, I knew that, cause otherwise we wouldn't be able to declare types with it. Sometimes I just get confused. So `decay_t<decltype(x[0])>` is really just the equivalent of `remove_reference_t<decltype(x[0])>`.

Comment: And cv qualifier too: `std::decay_t<const int&>` is `int`, `remove_reference_t<const int&>` is `const int`.