# I can't make unique_ptr of list<int> arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, list, stl, unique-ptr

This simple code can be compiled.

```
unique_ptr<list<int>> map1(new list<int>[10]);
```

But it causes seg falut when running.

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe02a4032e8: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

However this code successfully ran.

```
unique_ptr<int> map2(new int[10]);
```

Why array of list can not be made using unique_ptr?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both pieces of code have undefined behaviour and are broken.

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array)

Comment: A `list<int>` and a `list<int>[10]` are two different types

Comment: Why not `std::vector`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use unique_ptr version for dynamically allocated arrays:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::list<int>[]> map1(new std::list<int>[10]);
                              ^^ ~~~~~ !
```

See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr :

```
template <
    class T,
    class Deleter
> class unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>;
```

You can also use [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (as suggested in comments) with which you would get compile error instead of UB, as its interface protects against it:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::list<int>[]> up1 = std::make_unique<std::list<int>[]>(10);
auto up2 = std::make_unique<std::list<int>[]>(10);
```

[edit]

> However this code successfully ran.
>
> unique_ptr map2(new int[10]);

Its still Undefined Behaviour in above code, it may work or may cause seg fault. unique_ptr as above accepts any pointer but will always call `delete` during destructon. Calling `delete` on pointer which points to dynamically allocated array is UB. Thats why you need to call `delete[]` and this is what does `unique_ptr` for dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: And this is why one should use `std::make_unique`, to make it impossible to get the types wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A `A list<int>` and a `list<int>[10]` are two different types.  When you have a

```
unique_ptr<list<int>>
```

You are telling `unique_ptr` that it is going to point to a `list<int>`.  When the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope it is going to call `delete` to delete the underlying pointer.  Unfortunetly you initialize it with

```
new list<int>[10]
```

which needs to be deleted with `delete []` not `delete`.  This is the same for

```
unique_ptr<int> map2(new int[10]);
```

Why does the first version fail and the second does not?:  [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It is undefined behavior to call `delete` on something that has been `new[]`ed

So if you are going to use `new[]` in the constructor you need to use `type[]` for the type of the `unique_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::list<int>[]> map1(new std::list<int>[10]);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f01c64aa8c64cbdf)