# RAII char buffer

Tags: c++, raii

I'd like to wrap few C functions for safe C++ usage. There is a C function which takes raw pointer to array and its size, like -

```
void function(char* bufferToFill, size_t bufsize)
```

And now, I am having trouble finding C++ object which can expose a raw pointer to be passed to such function. I would like to avoid using new[] and keeping in mind to delete[] it every time I throw an exception.

std::string obviously cant expose its char*, std::vector similar, the only thing that comes to my mind is std::unique_ptr but it feels kinda odd (because its usually used to own an object, not array?)

Whats the proper C++ way to solve such problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like a valid use case for unique_ptr wrapping a C string, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array

Comment: @Pierre: `c_str` returns a `const` pointer, which is not adequate for a buffer to pass to a function that has to fill it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> std::string obviously cant expose its char*, std::vector similar

Of course they can; C++11 guarantees the storage for both `std::string`<sup>1</sup> and `std::vector` to be contiguous, so you can do `&str[0]` to obtain a pointer to the underlying data (*edit*: actually for `std::vector` `&str[0]` is not ok if `str.size()==0`, however the `data()` method is guaranteed to work always).

The validity of the pointer is subject to the usual references invalidation rules (i.e. it's valid as long as you don't perform any potentially reallocating operation).

#### Corner case: empty containers

While empty containers in this case are not an issue (why would someone pass a zero-length buffer to fill?) it's still useful to know that:

- for `std::string`, it's always safe to ask for `&str[0]`, even if the string is empty; in facts, the standard says explicitly (at [string.access]):

  > *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT()`; the referenced value shall not be modified.
- for `std::vector`, probably it's not ok to call `&str[0]` if the vector is empty; `operator[]` is specified in the general requirements for sequence containers, with operational semantic `*a.begin()`, which is undefined behavior if `size()` is 0; however, C++11 does provide the `data()` method, which always returns some kind of valid pointer (although to an empty valid range in the case of an empty vector)

Unfortunately, you cannot just remember that `data()` is correct for both containers, as for `std::string` it returns a `const` pointer exactly as `c_str()`.

---

1. In all the answer, where I say `std::string` I actually refer to any specialization of `std::basic_string`.

Comment: Isn't .data() best for std::array and std::vector, and .c_str() better for string?

Comment: Do note the string data may be reallocated should the string change, and the pointer would become dangling.

Comment: @Robinson: `data` should be the same (at least, for non-empty vectors); `c_str()` is `const`.

Comment: @hauron: of course, I was adding the remark in this very moment =)

Answer (score 7):

> the only thing that comes to my mind is std::unique_ptr but it feels kinda odd (because its usually used to own an object, not array?)

Another misconception here.

An array is an object, and [the language specifically allows for `std::unique_ptr` of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16711697/560648):

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);
```