# Contructor for matrix class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, matrix, constructor

I am writing a matrix manipulation class in C++ as a course project. I want the syntax to be as close to MATLAB as possible. I wish to implement a constructor for the matrix which allows me to do something like what is shown below:

```
Matrix X(3,3) = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
//     [1  2  3]
// X = [4  5  6]
//     [7  8  9]
```

I have tried using an `initializer_list` constructor but that only allows me to do:

```
Matrix X(3,3,{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
```

Here's my code for this constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(size_t row, size_t col) : nrow(row), ncol(col), len(row*col) {
    mat = std::unique_ptr<double[]>(new double[len]);
}

void Matrix::operator= (std::initializer_list<double> list) {
    if (list.size() != len)
        throw std::length_error("Sizes of matrix and initializer list do not match");
    auto it = list.begin();
    for (int i = 0; it != list.end(); ++i, ++it)
        mat[i] = *it;
}

Matrix::Matrix(size_t row, size_t col, std::initializer_list<double> list) : Matrix::Matrix(row, col) {
    *this = list;
}
```

I need suggestions on how to implement the first one.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<double>` instead of a `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I may be completely wrong but I think arrays are faster and lighter as compared to vectors.

Comment: A `std::vector` performance wise should be just as fast.  You still have a memory allocation in both cases and afterwards access speed should be the same.

Comment: @LakshayGarg Unfortunately, people here often downvote questions if what they are asking is impossible.

Comment: Just as a side note, opencv has a particular way to do this: `Mat m = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 0,-1,0,-1,5,-1,0,-1,0);` though its a bit more complicated to implement

Comment: Check out the Armadillo project for ideas. They also implemented a Matrix API (and more) that tried to emulate Matlab as much as possible. As mentioned OpenCV has also done similar things, there are quite a few matrix libraries out there. Given its for school you'll obviously want to write your own still, but you should look at how other people have solved that problem when formulating your own solution.

Comment: @NathanOliver I did some timing by using std::vector and std::unique_pointer and I find that the time for constructing a matrix is smaller in case of std::unique_ptr. Also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array

PS: I tried timing a matrix of size 10000 x 10000

Comment: @LakshayGarg I think you were using the wrong construction.  I see no difference [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0894881503a5a8e)

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes! you're right. I was using `resize` that is why it took more time. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @LakshayGarg No problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver There's a catch. When you use `reserve`, you increase the vector capacity but its size is still 0. So you may get incorrect results if any of your methods use iterators without actually pushing anything into the vector.

Comment: @LakshayGarg *I did some timing* -- Always mention what type of build you're timing.  If you're timing an unoptimized or "debug" version, your results are meaningless.

Comment: @LakshayGarg Yes there is that but you have that same cost with what you are doing with the pointer.  the usage may differ slightly but the performance should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the syntax.

```
Matrix X(3,3) = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

is not legal c++, since you are using both the [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) syntax and the [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) syntax in one declaration. This means what you want to do can't work. You can, however, do something like this:

```
Matrix X(3,3);
X = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

which I believe will work with your code.