# unique_ptr : calling make_unique twice one after the other

Tags: pointers, unique

`1 std::unique_ptr< Test[] > upt(std::make_unique< Test[] >(2));`

> //No leak here, as it does reset, which will deallocate.

`3 upt = (std::make_unique< Test[] >(1));`

In the above snippet, on call to line 3, twice destructors of Test gets called, and allocates memory for array of size 1,

So, who call the reset? Is it `make_unique` does it?
Also, can I get detail implementation of `make_unique` and `make_shared`.

Comment: It can't be `make_unique`. It has to be `operator=`.

Comment: class Test
{
private:
 int m_a;

public:
 Test(int i)
  :m_a(i) {}

 Test()
  :m_a(0) {}
 ~Test()
 {
  std::cout << "Test: dtor\n";
 }
 int geta() { return m_a; }
 void seta(int a) { m_a = a; }
};

Comment: For future readers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806616/reassign-unique-ptr-object-with-make-unique-statements-memory-leak/37806844