# Set class member unique_ptr<T[]> array without copying

Tags: c++, move-semantics, unique-ptr, initializer-list, rvalue

I have a class containing a c-style array managed with unique_ptr. I want to provide a constructor:

```
class A {
  unique_ptr<T[]> p;
public:
  A(int d, X x) : p(new T[d]) {
    //Transfer from x to p without copying
  }
}
```

so that I can build my object with something like:

```
int main(..) {
  A a{n,{expr1,expr2,..}};
}
```

where {expr1,expr2,..} contains the values (evaluated at runtime) for the inizialization. Since this list is temporary, it seems to me a waste of resources to build it, copying its values into the actual object and discard it.

I believe that with move semantincs, rvalues and all the nice features of C++11 there should be a solution for this simple task, but I could not find it (I'm quite new in C++).

I would like to stick with c-style arrays and don't move to std::vectors. Is there a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "without copying"? You want the heap allocation to be initialized with the data members?

Comment: Don't use `unique_ptr` for arrays. Use `std::array`, `std::vector` or `std::string` as pointed out by @Ðаn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use perfect forwarding:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct S
{
    S(int) {}
    S(S const&) = delete;
    S(S&&) = default;
};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> p;

    template<typename... Args>
    A(int d, Args&&... args)
        : p(new T[sizeof...(args)]{std::forward<Args>(args)...})
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);

    A<std::string> b(0, "hello", "world!", "\n");

    S s(0);
    A<S> c(0, std::move(s), 2, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are tow points I'd like to make here.

1. AFAICS, `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` offers you very little benefit over the standard C++ solution of using a `std::vector<T>`, namely a reduced memory footprint (64 instead of 128 bytes for the container itself on a 64bit machine and potentially also of the amount of heap used), but see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array). Any newby to C++ should stick to `std::vector`.
2. Move semantics are only beneficial for objects that manage memory on the heap ('free store'). So only if your `expr1`, `expr2` etc are object which themselves keep track of allocated memory, does moving have any meaning. This does not appear the case here, so just copy.

Comment: Re. 2, `T` might be `std::string` or some more compliated class

Comment: @Walter I don't fully understand your second comment. Maybe I'm getting everything wrong but I can imagine someone to build a temporary object on the stack and than "move" this object as data member of a class.

Comment: @user8066678 You seem to not have grasped the idea of moving yet. If you create a temporary object on the stack, you cannot move it. Moving means: copy the pointer to an object on the heap (rather than copying the object itself), but then ensure that the pointer variable copied from is reset to null. It is similar to what otherwise is referred to a 'shallow copy' (e.g. in python).