# Return an array from a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to implement a function that returns an array, I came to this solution, but I don't know if it is a good practice, that's how I did it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* returnNewArray(int n) {
    int* arr = new int[n];

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        arr[i] = i;
    
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int* arr = returnNewArray(n);

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    
    delete[] arr;
    arr = NULL;

    cout << endl;

}
```

I wonder if it is necessary to deallocate the memory that I allocated in the function to create the dynamic array (arr).

Comment: If you call new[] somewhere you should call delete[] on the same pointer when you are done with the memory. With that said when your program ends your OS will release all memory allocated.

Comment: No, it's not good practice. Return a `std::vector<int>`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/n5jErdfWd)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what you're supposed to do. You can also try smart pointers which will do this automatically for you

Comment: To see your options, I suggest you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array

Comment: @BitTickler I updated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24852984/7582247) with the C++20 option I used in my answer.

Comment: This might seem pedantic, but actually it important to properly understand the difference, You are not returning an array (that's actually impossible in C++) you are returning a pointer (which in this case happens to point to a dynamically allocated array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know if it is a good practice

It's not. Nowadays, cases where using `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` are necessary are very few.

> I wonder if it is necessary to deallocate the memory that I allocated in the function

It is necessary if you want to avoid memory leaks and since you used a raw owning pointer, you need to do it manually, just like you do in your code. Your code is cleaning up correctly.

Good practice would however be to use a [`std::vector<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or at least use a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr<int[]>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead since these will clean up memory automatically when they go out of scope.

`vector<int>` version:

```cpp
#include <numeric> // std::iota
#include <vector>  // std::vector

std::vector<int> returnNewArray(size_t n) {
    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);     // [0, n)
    return arr;
}
```

`unique_ptr<int[]>` version:

```cpp
#include <memory>  // std::unique_ptr / std::make_unique_for_overwrite
#include <numeric> // std::iota

std::unique_ptr<int[]> returnNewArray(size_t n) {
    auto arr = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(n);
    std::iota(arr.get(), arr.get() + n, 0);   // [0, n)
    return arr;
}
```

Both versions will let you iterate over the result just like you do in your code - and you don't have to `delete[]` anything when you're done:

```cpp
auto arr = returnNewArray(n);
    
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    std::cout << arr[i] << '\t';  // 0  1  2  3  4
```

But the `std::vector<int>` has the benefit of knowing its own size and can be used in range based for-loops, which also helps to not accidentally access the array out-of-bounds:

```cpp
for (int value : arr)             // range based for-loop
    std::cout << value << '\t';   // 0  1  2  3  4
```