allocate as std::byte[10], deallocate as short*
I come to C and C++ from Assembly before 2.5 decades.
I inherited some things implied in assembly, to both C and C++, but later I realized that these things are actually undefined behavior.
One of these was the difference between delete ptr and delete[] array which for OS is usually one call because there are no destructors.
My latest assumption is the following code:
std::byte *a = new std::byte[10];
short *b = reinterpret_cast<short*>(a);
delete[] b;

Is this undefined behavior? There are no destructors at all.

Just to clarify.  Do you really mean reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(a)?  Or should that be reinterpret_cast<short*>(a)?

Your title doesn't match the code either

And also why would you use std::byte - just use short to begin with (or better unsigned short).

Allocating using new with one type and deallocating using delete and another type is undefined behaviour. I doubt in practice you would get any problems if there are no destructors, but it's still undefined behaviour.

The standard explicitly says: "In an array delete expression, if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted is not similar to its static type, the behavior is undefined." https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3

BTW: Nobody mentioned it, but the worst part here is that you're doing manual memory management. Use array<>, vector<> or smart pointers, but not two separate pieces of code that must match but that are many lines apart. Make it easy for you by making it hard to get it wrong! ;)

Do you know about the guidelines for C++? Try to avoid calling new/delete explicitly. use std::vector<std::uint8_t> a.  On top of that using a reinterpret_cast to short* is just asking for trouble (the result will depend on the endianess of the computer your code runs one). Also have a go at learncpp.com C++ is nothing like it was 2 and half decades ago

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array#16711846 -- take a look at this and the extensive discussion. I think that should change the way you approach such code.

The answer to the question in the title is no, never.

Yes, it is undefined behavior. The type given to the delete[] expression must be similar to the actual type of the object it refers to.
"similar" means essentially that it can only differ in const-qualifications.
Similarly doing almost anything else with b (except casting it back to std::byte*) will have undefined behavior. This kind of reinterpret_cast will usually end in undefined behavior. There are only a few very specific use cases that are well-defined.
In C++, contrary to assembly, there is an object model and you need to think in terms of these objects which hold values specific to their type, not in terms of memory locations that hold untyped bits which can be interpreted as any type for any operation.
