# Assigning to uninitialized memory in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, new-operator

If I have code like this that would be legal in C:

```
int* i = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int)));
*i = 123;
```

Is this also legal C++, or would it invoke undefined/implementation-defined behavior? And for what types would it be legal?

Or would it be needed to do `new(i) int (123);` already in this case?

For non-trivial classes for example, it could not be legal, because the object is never constructed, but then its `operator=` is called.

Comment: `int* i = std::malloc(sizeof(int));` [won't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/fqMos345n). Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Which version of C++ are you compiling against, that does change the answer.

Comment: You'll need to cast the result of `malloc` to `int*` to compile it. But even if it's legal - why would you want to do that ?

Comment: Changed the question to cast the pointer. But the idea is that `i` is an `int*` pointer to uninitialized memory (for example, coming from `std::allocator<int>::allocate()` or other)

Comment: [Uninitialized memory in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254130/uninitialized-memory-in-c)

Comment: C++20 adds a rather obtuse wording to make this work. [`malloc()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#4) and some other functions are blessed to magically "create" objects in the allocated memory. See also [implicit lifetime types](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#def:type,implicit-lifetime).

Comment: @tmlen "_(for example, coming from std::allocator<int>::allocate() or other)_": The answer to the question majorly depends on how exactly the pointer is obtained. In particular for `std::allocator<int>::allocate` the answer will be different than for `malloc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is legal since C++20. It was technically illegal before that, but worked in practice anyway.

This normally would be UB due to accessing an object before its lifetime starts, but C++20 added [`[intro.object]/11`](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#11):

> Some operations are described as *implicitly creating objects* within a specified region of storage.
> For each operation that is specified as implicitly creating objects, that operation implicitly creates and starts the lifetime of zero or more objects of implicit-lifetime types ([basic.types.general]) in its specified region of storage if doing so would result in the program having defined behavior.
> If no such set of objects would give the program defined behavior, the behavior of the program is undefined.
> If multiple such sets of objects would give the program defined behavior, it is unspecified which such set of objects is created.
>
> *[Note 4: Such operations do not start the lifetimes of subobjects of such objects that are not themselves of implicit-lifetime types.
> — end note]*

`malloc()` is blessed for this in [`[c.malloc]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#4):

> These functions implicitly create objects ([intro.object]) in the returned region of storage and return a pointer to a suitable created object.
> In the case of calloc and realloc, the objects are created before the storage is zeroed or copied, respectively.

(Note "returns a pointer to a suitable created object", otherwise `std::launder()` would be required.)

This works for "implicit lifetime types": [`[basic.types.general]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#term.implicit.lifetime.type)

> ... Scalar types, implicit-lifetime class types ([class.prop]), array types, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called implicit-lifetime types.

[`[class.prop]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#9)

> A class S is an implicit-lifetime class if
>
> (9.1) — it is an aggregate whose destructor is not user-provided or
>
> (9.2) — it has at least one trivial eligible constructor and a trivial, non-deleted destructor.

(9.1) sounds confusing until you read "Note 4" in the first quote in this answer.

Comment: Wasn't (the lack of) implicit object creation a defect? I think since it's a defect report, it's legal when compiling with older versions too (but I'm not sure)

Comment: @Artyer Not sure either. Either way it didn't cause issues in practice.

Comment: It seems crazy how C++ first pretends that `int`s are objects that need to be created and destroyed, even when it is obviously just raw memory. And then complicates it even more by adding a special concept of "implicit lifetime class", just so that modern optimizers won't destroy the entire program once the UB is invoked...

Comment: @tmlen These rules are essentially just clearer specifications of C's aliasing rules of effective types. They are an improvement over what C currently has. General class types are not included, because that would allow violating their class invariants by implicit object creation. The result is a compromise of this with compatibility to C.

Answer (score 2):

This is well defined from C++20 onwards as per [intro.object#11](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#11). The standard even has an example similar to this where the pointer obtained from `std::malloc` is dereferenced.

From [intro.object](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#13):

> [Example]
>
> ```
> #include <cstdlib>
> struct X { int a, b; };
> X *make_x() {
>  // The call to std​::​malloc implicitly creates an object of type X
>  // and its subobjects a and b, and returns a pointer to that X object
>  // (or an object that is pointer-interconvertible ([basic.compound]) with it),
>  // in order to give the subsequent class member access operations
>  // defined behavior.
>  X *p = (X*)std::malloc(sizeof(struct X));
>  p->a = 1;
>  p->b = 2;
>  return p;
> }
> ```
>
> end exmaple]