# performance comparsion between vector and raw c-style array

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I have profiled the performance between c++ vector and c-style array.  The result is a little bit unexpected since the literature says the performance of vector should come very close to raw array, but it does not.  Did I do anything wrong in my profiling?

```
void getVector1(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument(std::string("negative argument n:") + std::to_string(n));
    }

    auto tp1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<int> ivec(n);
    int i = 0;
    for (auto& x : ivec)
    {
        x = ++i;
    }

    auto tp2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro> dd = tp2 - tp1;

    printf("spend %6.2f us time to create: %d elements vector inside %s() at %s:%d \n", dd.count(), n, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
}


void getVector2(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument(std::string("negative argument n:") + std::to_string(n));
    }

    auto tp1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto pvec = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        pvec[i] = i;
    }

    auto tp2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro> dd = tp2 - tp1;

    delete[] pvec;
    printf("spend %6.2f us time to create: %d elements vector inside %s() at %s:%d \n", dd.count(), n, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
}



int main()
{
    int n = 10000000;
    getVector1(n);
    getVector2(n);

    return 0;
}
```

The code  was compiled using g++ with -O3 option.

spend 11946.38 us time to create: 10000000 elements vector inside getVector1() at testVectorSpeed.cpp

spend 7298.66 us time to create: 10000000 elements vector inside getVector2() at testVectorSpeed.cpp

Comment: It might be helpful to time the creation separately from the loop that fills it in.

Comment: Also, check the generated code, it might have optimized the second loop out.

Comment: I would expect a good compiler to realize that you dont use the vector or the array, try use them (outside of the timing). Also you should run the measurement several times and also change the order of the calls

Comment: @user463035818 heap elision is not in gcc yet AFAIK, so the side effects should still kick in.

Comment: When you create the vector, there is a call to `memset()`, because the ints are default-constructed. If you used `reserve()` and `emplace_back()` instead, you would probably get much better performance out of it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3664272/1896169

Comment: One real difference is that elements in vector are default-initialized, but no much in the dynamic array. Try `vec = new int[n]();`

Comment: If my answer answered your question, you can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/218012) by clicking on the check mark. If it didn't answer your question, can you comment to elaborate on what you are missing?

Answer (score 8):

This cost comes down to vector zeroing out the memory via its allocator.

---

First, it's always a good idea to use a benchmarking library like [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) rather than rolling your own benchmarking. We can use [quick-bench.com](http://quick-bench.com/) to quickly use the library. Rewriting your code to use this:

```
// Just the benchmark code:
void getVector1(benchmark::State& state)
{
    int n = state.range(0);

    for (auto _ : state) {
      std::vector<int> ivec(n);

      // This is the same operation that you are doing
      std::iota(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), 1);

      // We don't want the compiler to see that we aren't
      // using `ivec` and thus optimize away the entire
      // loop body
      benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ivec);
    }
}

void getArray1(benchmark::State& state)
{
    int n = state.range(0);

    for (auto _ : state) {
      auto pvec = new int[n];

      std::iota(pvec, pvec + n, 1);

      benchmark::DoNotOptimize(pvec);

      delete[] pvec;
    }
}

// Smaller number still reproduces it
BENCHMARK(getVector1)->Arg(10000);
BENCHMARK(getArray1)->Arg(10000);
```

[image: benchmark OP's code]

<sup>[Click on image for quick-bench link](http://quick-bench.com/y4zFikxcCfOG3WDR28wiPImYs_4)</sup>

Through a little playing around, we can find that the cost difference is just the cost of zeroing out the memory with [`std::uninitialized_fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill) ([on quick-bench](http://quick-bench.com/afriPoSNT7obG11QvFK4ZImSucA)).

Indeed, if we instead use [an allocator that leaves the memory uninitialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41049640/1896169), there is no measurable difference between the two:

```
// Allocator from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41049640
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class default_init_allocator : public A {
    typedef std::allocator_traits<A> a_t;
public:
    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration
    using A::A; // Inherit constructors from A

    template <typename U> struct rebind {
        using other =
            default_init_allocator
            <  U, typename a_t::template rebind_alloc<U>  >;
    };

    template <typename U>
    void construct(U* ptr)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<U>::value) {
        ::new(static_cast<void*>(ptr)) U;
    }

    template <typename U, typename...Args>
    void construct(U* ptr, Args&&... args) {
        a_t::construct(static_cast<A&>(*this),
            ptr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

void getVector1(benchmark::State& state)
{
    int n = state.range(0);

    for (auto _ : state) {
      std::vector<int, default_init_allocator<int>> ivec(n);

      std::iota(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), 1);

      benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ivec);
    }
}

void getArray1(benchmark::State& state)
{
    int n = state.range(0);

    for (auto _ : state) {
      auto pvec = new int[n];

      std::iota(pvec, pvec + n, 1);

      benchmark::DoNotOptimize(pvec);

      delete[] pvec;
    }
}

BENCHMARK(getVector1)->Arg(10000);
BENCHMARK(getArray1)->Arg(10000);
```

[image: benchmark uninitialized allocator]

<sup>[Click on image for quick-bench link](http://quick-bench.com/cxLdWpcZ9P48d0O06Wjx9e6ao8I)</sup>

Comment: Honestly I suspect you could get this same result just using `reserve` and `emplace_back` instead.

Comment: @Mgetz Using `reserve` and `emplace_back` [is actually really slow](http://quick-bench.com/3y54BE2_w92f64vc9ZtMEv7FFNw) (even if I use `std::back_inserter` with `std::iota`, which is slightly different, but still...). I thought so too, but it's even worse than the original vector code

Comment: Something smells, I'd want to profile that directly to get the hot line

Comment: @Mgetz Please do! I really want to know why it's worse. I've been using `reserve` + `emplace_back` all over the place in my own code. I'd love to see what you can find

Comment: @Mgetz Looking at [the disassembly on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/PqdX9f), for gcc it seems that the code keeps checking whether the capacity needs to be increased, even though we know it doesn't. For clang, it seems that clang couldn't produce vectorized instructions with the `reserve` + `emplace_back` version

Comment: You'd think that could be optimized out if you make `n` `const`

Comment: I'd be curious to see how it fairs with something more complicated than `int` to be honest... something that required more complicated construction.

Comment: @Mgetz Yes, for more complex types, it [performs just fine](http://quick-bench.com/9p7fgdqnB-FsgbGcjvRNs_fFF_8), and if the default constructor does more work, it could out-perform

Comment: @Justin I do not see how vector could out perform. AFAIK it always does >= amount of work as the array(in some cases value construction is more expansive than default construction, in some it is the same)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl In that comment, I was referring to using vector by `vector(n)` and `vector[i] = ...` vs `vector.reserve(n)` and `vector.emplace_back(...)`. I was saying that the latter can outperform the former when the default constructor of the type does notable work. For example, suppose `MyType`'s default constructor allocated memory. All those allocations would be wasted, since I'm going to overwrite it anyway. That's why `reserve` + `emplace_back` can outperform `vector(n)` + `vector[i] = ...`

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It's also worth noting that with `new MyType[n]`, the default constructor will also be run, so vector `reserve` + `emplace_back` can outperform in that case

Comment: Ah ok. Also There is related proposal (it is for string, not vector) http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1072r0.html