# c++ how to create std::string containing size uninitialized bytes?

Tags: c++, optimization, std, stdstring

i need a std::string of `size` bytes, after constructing it i am going to write to every byte in that string prior to reading from it, thus null-initializing the string is a waste of cpu, this works:

```
std::string s(size,0);
```

but it's just slightly wasteful, it's basically like using `calloc()` when all i need is `malloc()`, so the question is, how do i construct a string of X uninitialized bytes?

(using reserve()+push is not an option because im giving the string to a C-api taking `char*,size` to do the actual initialization)

edit: this thread seems to about the same issue/related (but with vectors instead of strings): [Value-Initialized Objects in C++11 and std::vector constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097783/value-initialized-objects-in-c11-and-stdvector-constructor/15119665#)

Comment: If its about optimization, and only malloc() is efficient enough, why not use it? It is not like it`s forbidden.

Comment: Perhaps `std::string` isn't the correct choice here? Perhaps you should be using a plain array (possibly dynamically allocated) instead? You can always put it into a `std::string` (or `std::string_view`) later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with `std::string`. But it can be achieved different way, like using `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.

```
auto pseudo_string = std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[size]);
```

Or if your compiler supports C++20

```
auto pseudo_string = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<char[]>(size);
```

Comment: Wouldn't all the elements of the array be value-initialized by [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)?

Comment: @songyuanyao take a look at your own link overload (2) and (5)

Comment: It appears a that c++20 introduces `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` to do just this.

Comment: @bartop ? Then shouldn't `make_unique_for_overwrite` be used instead?

Comment: it's a compelling alternative and i have upvoted your post, but i think it may be possible with std::string() nontheless, because std::string default constructor accepts a `const allocator_type& allocator` if you want to use a custom allocator, and i think the default string constructor depends on the allocator to do the null-initialization, thus i think it would be possible to supply a custom allocator that simply doesn't initialize... i haven't actually tried it though, just speculation at this point. anyway thanks for the alternative!

Comment: - i tested the custom allocator theory, and no, even with a custom allocator, initialization of the string will be done by the string constructor post-allocation ( https://wandbox.org/permlink/HfH7wENQ0XuS61ye )